# How can I create a aggregate data from 3 different tables in just 1 table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I hope you all are doing great! :D

I need your help to get the following done:

I need to create the following table:

| Date | Revenue gained from new deals | Revenue lost from churn | Revenue gained from upsell |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/jan/2022 | $1000 | -$500 | $1000 |
| 02/jan/2022 | $2000 | -$200 | $2000 |

The situation here is that to gather and aggregate this data I need to fetch 3 different tables:

*deals, churns and upsells*

**The *deals* table:**

| Deal | Closing date | Revenue won |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Deal #1 | 01/jan/2022 | $500 |
| Deal #2 | 01/jan/2022 | $500 |
| Deal #3 | 02/jan/2022 | $1500 |
| Deal #4 | 02/jan/2022 | $500 |

**The *churns* table:**

| Churn | Closing date | Revenue lost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Churn #1 | 01/jan/2022 | -$500 |
| Churn #2 | 02/jan/2022 | -$100 |
| Churn #3 | 02/jan/2022 | -$100 |

**The *upsells* table:**

| Upsell | Closing date | Revenue won |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Upsell #1 | 01/jan/2022 | $2000 |
| Upsell #2 | 01/jan/2022 | -$1000 |
| Upsell #3 | 02/jan/2022 | $2000 |

The first question is:
How can I create a SQL command to get this done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your data look the same as in the question? Can you share the DDL statements for your tables?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the subquery doing aggregation for churns and upsells tables.

Something like below:

```
select d.Closing_date,
       sum(d.Revenue_won) as 'Revenue gained from new deals', 
       c.`Revenue lost from churn`,
       u.`Revenue gained from upsell`
from deals d
inner join ( select Closing_date,
                    sum(Revenue_lost) as 'Revenue lost from churn'
            from churns 
            group by Closing_date 
            ) as c on c.Closing_date=d.Closing_date
inner join ( select Closing_date,
                    sum(Revenue_won) as 'Revenue gained from upsell'
             from upsells u 
             group by Closing_date 
             ) as u on  u.Closing_date=d.Closing_date          
group by d.Closing_date ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0875563c9ab7f9385711dde21cd98b47

Please do not store date as text, you will face many difficulties. If you want to format the date you could use [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

*Note*. If some other date exists on deals table and not on the two other table it will be filtered out from the results. If you want it use `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN`.

***Edit*

```
select d.Closing_date,
       d.`Revenue gained from new deals`,
       c.`Revenue lost from churn`,
       u.`Revenue gained from upsell`
from  ( select Closing_date,
               sum(Revenue_won) as 'Revenue gained from new deals'
        from deals 
        group by Closing_date ) as d 
inner join ( select Closing_date,
                    sum(Revenue_lost) as 'Revenue lost from churn'
            from churns 
            group by Closing_date 
            ) as c on c.Closing_date=d.Closing_date
inner join ( select Closing_date,
                    sum(Revenue_won) as 'Revenue gained from upsell'
             from upsells u 
             group by Closing_date 
             ) as u on  u.Closing_date=d.Closing_date           ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/S61QeLBX

Comment: Just a note.  In general, you should use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` to avoid filtering `deals` data.

Comment: @Alexey right, but my answer is based on the data examples and I supposed that if , for example `03/jan/2022`  exists on deals table it should be filtered out. I will update the question adding a note on this part

Comment: Dear @Ergest Basha, thanks so much for your help!

I've tried on my side and it returned the following error:

`Kindly check the following in the query.

1.All non-aggregate columns used in the SELECT and ORDER BY clause are also used in GROUP BY clause.

2.Having Clause can not be used with out Group by clause.

3.Alias names can not be used in HAVING clause. Provide the exact column names or expressions in HAVING clause.

4.Non-integer constants cannot be used in GROUP BY AND  ORDER BY clauses`

I created this query on my Analytics tool: Zoho Analytics.

Comment: @RodrigoMoro check the updated answer

Comment: Hello @ErgestBasha, the updated answer worked pretty well, the issue that we've found on our side is that whenever one date is not present on the 3 tables, this date is not shown in the output table at all:

For example, I have a deal ($500) on the 4th Sept and I don't have any churns neighter upsells, the date 4th Sept is not present on the output table, 

I'm trying to figure out how can I workaround this, if you have any idea, please let me know!

Thanks SO MUCH for your help so far!

Comment: @RodrigoMoro I left a note on the answer , to fix this detail you should use left join instead of inner join, be sure that the first  table on the left should have all the values

Answer (score 0):

since the tables aren't linked just run 3 queries and do the post-processing
in the backend

Comment: *since the tables aren't linked*, maybe the date could link them ?